# htaccess hashtags anchor issues

Tags: html, .htaccess

first of all sorry if the title of my question doesn't explain what I need well but I really can't figure out what to call this.

At my job we finally moved from .html to .php pages so we can run additional code we did using htaccess to check if a php version of the page exists, so if you are looking for products.html it will send you to products.php etc. This code works exactly the way we want it to redirect those pages:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Ever since we did this we had issues with links that were meant to scroll down the page like "#footer" or to scroll to top by just having "#" as the href, these links now all go back to the home page (with the hash content in the url like domain.com/#footer) and that's a big issue we are trying to fix, we are attributing this issue to the htaccess change since it's the only change we made at the time.

Thank you in advance for any information on how to solve this issue

***UPDATED
Ok so as it turns out it was the base tag on the head of the html that has been causing the issue, now i need to figure why that started happening since we've always had it and never had issues.

Comment: Why don't you change all files from .html to .php? It should be easy with a script. Additionaly, could you post a little piece of html code with some anchors?

Comment: Is the above your full htaccess file? That code works for me.

Comment: Can you capture activity output in Firebug while you click on this links and post it here.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the answers,as far as the html code goes, it's pretty straight forwards <a href="#top">back to top</a> There is more to the htaccess but it's main 301 redirects of old pages, also the reason I can't just switch is because of search engines having already indexed our pages and many customers having links to us to those html pages so that's why i have to have that code there, also i want them to look as if they were html pages only.